# LIBGDX: How could I detect if user is doing a known shape or pattern with her finger

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touch, shapes

I'm having hard time explaining this, but anyway, I want to make a LIBGDX-game where you can cast spells by "drawing" shapes or patterns with your finger. How could I make it?

I have made a lot of research but didn't find anything even near what I was looking for. I would really appreciate your knowledge.

Here are some examples how I would like to cast a spell:

[image: Pattern 1]

[image: Pattern 2]